# How to slice elements between other elements with python

Tags: python-3.x

i have list with numbers and i want to slice all the elements between numbers 192 that exist on the list and pass them to a list

my list

[192, 0, 1, 0, 1, 192, 12, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 66, 218, 0, 10, 5, 115, 116, 97, 116, 115, 1, 108, 192, 20, 192, 53, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 162, 0, 4, 74, 125, 133, 155, 192, 53, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 162, 0, 4, 74, 125, 133, 156, 192, 53, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 162, 0, 4, 74, 125, 133, 154, 192, 53, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 162, 0, 4, 74, 125, 133, 157]

i want someting like this

[192, 0, 1, 0, 1 ]

[192, 12, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 66, 218, 0, 10, 5, 115, 116, 97, 116, 115, 1, 108]

[192, 20, 192, 53, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 162, 0, 4, 74, 125, 133, 155]

until the end of the list.

Comment: The third line in the sample output is incorrect, there are two slices in that line, the first one goes from 192 to 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible way to do it:

```
# input list
lst = [192, 0, 1, 0, 1, 192, 12, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 66, 218, 0, 10, 5, 115, 116, 97, 116, 115, 1, 108, 192, 20, 192, 53, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 162, 0, 4, 74, 125, 133, 155, 192, 53, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 162, 0, 4, 74, 125, 133, 156, 192, 53, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 162, 0, 4, 74, 125, 133, 154, 192, 53, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 162, 0, 4, 74, 125, 133, 157]
# list of indexes where 192 is found,
# plus one extra index for the final slice
indexes = [i for i, n in enumerate(lst) if n == 192] + [len(lst)]
# create the slices between consecutive indexes
[lst[indexes[i]:indexes[i+1]] for i in range(len(indexes) - 1)]
```

The result will be:

```
[[192, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [192, 12, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 66, 218, 0, 10, 5, 115, 116, 97, 116, 115, 1, 108],
 [192, 20],
 [192, 53, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 162, 0, 4, 74, 125, 133, 155],
 [192, 53, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 162, 0, 4, 74, 125, 133, 156],
 [192, 53, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 162, 0, 4, 74, 125, 133, 154],
 [192, 53, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 162, 0, 4, 74, 125, 133, 157]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a generator with `itertools.groupby` that uses 192's equality method as a key function, pair the output of the generator with `zip` and then use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to join the pairs (the example below assumes your list is stored in variable `l`):

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
i = (list(g) for _, g in groupby(l, key=(192).__eq__))
[list(chain.from_iterable(p)) for p in zip(i, i)]
```

This returns:

```
[[192, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [192, 12, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 66, 218, 0, 10, 5, 115, 116, 97, 116, 115, 1, 108],
 [192, 20],
 [192, 53, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 162, 0, 4, 74, 125, 133, 155],
 [192, 53, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 162, 0, 4, 74, 125, 133, 156],
 [192, 53, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 162, 0, 4, 74, 125, 133, 154],
 [192, 53, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 162, 0, 4, 74, 125, 133, 157]]
```